# Send SMS using phone from computer

Tags: java, sms, gsm, sms-gateway, kannel

I need my computer program to be able to send and receive SMS messages. The software has to run independent of the Internet so using a web based SMS gateway is not the solution.

The software should be running from a linux or a Windows machine. Windows is more important for my usecase. My program is in Java but I guess there may be solutions independent of the programming language.

I am considering one of the following options.

Kannel http://www.kannel.org/ Although supported for Linux I guess I could find a way to compile it in windows like done here: http://www.ddj.co.za/kannel-for-windows

The other one seems a more lightweight option http://smsj.sourceforge.net/

Which of these or something else that you have in mind could be a better way of sending SMS via computer without an internet connection?

I am considering using these libraries so I don't have to program all the AT Commands.

Also how do I connect my phone to the computer? For example will it be fine if I just connect my phone with a USB cable when using kannel.

Update:
I need to use simple GSM phones and not depend on IOS or Android specific features.

Comment: I'm not the down voter but beware of asking questions with no "best" answer. I learned the hard way :)

Comment: well sometimes one does need to chose a good library given some constraints.

Comment: I agree, you just must be careful of asking open endedly.

Comment: You might want to ask this over at programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not want you needed or wanted, but maybe useful for others: When I had my iPhone jailbroken there was an Cydia app I used to send SMS from my computer through my phone, [BiteSMS](http://bitesms.com/).

You had to ssh in and then something similar to:

```
/Applications/biteSMS.app/biteSMS -send -carrier 077xxxxxx “The message goes here”
```

Obviously you replace 077xxx with the number you want to send to.

It looks like it is fairly similar process with Android, check out [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18344/rooted-phone-sending-sms-message-via-command-line) question on doing this through Android. Again this requires a ssh connection to the phone. Also have a google on 'Sending sms from commandline' there are other resources available.

As for other methods, I can't see any viable options without attaching a phone to your computer and accessing the OS and ssh seems the easiest way to do this.

Comment: actually forgot to add to the question that I may have to use a simple GSM phone for some usecases.

Answer (score 0):

Try smslib.org + some GSM modem.